# laravel 5.1 white screen error;

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am working on a project and i just completed some tasks; eventually we need to deploy it on ftp for test.
I am stuck right there when it shows only the blank page; .htaccess file is working, index.php is also reachable; it works up to line 50 of index.php:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
// upto this every thing is fine but
```

After this line echo command is not working means error is right there

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
 );
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I set appropriate permission to folders storage and bootstrap; and php version is 5.5.9. 
How can i shoot this problem; it took really long time what's the problem with it

Comment: Any error information in the logs?

Comment: Did you set the debug option on?

Comment: yes debug option is true

Comment: And what do you expect to get? Are you checking the controller of the default page? There is not much information

Comment: i expect default welcome page.... it has error in this page then i can't do anything with it

Comment: Just to be stupid. Is it a fresh laravel install? And have you edited any php file in the public directory?

Comment: Can you post that error that you are talking about

Comment: there no public directory because i remove it; place all files under public folder are drag down to root folder and i configured it; on first url it will display default welcome page.... there is no need to remove default welcome page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a guess able answer is here possible.

I guess you are missing a php module like curl or you did not enable fopen wrappers for http/url. This depends what "Illuminate\Http" is using.

Try to enable the php error log.

Comment: try to generate php error- it really helps to get the problem , actually  PDO is not enabled in shared server

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but I reached here looking for the same error.
Turned out to be a malformed .env file.
I wanted to set the APP_NAME with spaces and was setting the variable like this:

```
APP_NAME=CAFS API
```

The correct implementation is to surround the string with quotation marks:

```
APP_NAME="CAFS API"
```